# Fetching Course List for Student

Tags: hibernate

I want to fetch course details with respect to a particular student. How can I do this in Hibernate ?

Please help me in hibernate.

```
@Entity
public class Course implements Serializable {

    private long id;
    private String name;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "Enrollment", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "Course_Id", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "Student_Id", insertable = false, nullable = false, updatable = false)})
    private List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

}


@Entity
public class Student implements Serializable {

    private long id;
    private String name;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

}
```

Help me to find details for courses with respect to student.

Comment: what have you tried? if you post the code where you try the fetching we can pick from there and help

Answer (score 0):

If multiple courses are there for a single student then your database structure should be like :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Student")
public class Student implements Serializable {


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="ID")
private long id;


@Column(name="NAME")
private String name;


@OneToMany(mappedBy="student",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)   // change to FetchType.Lazy for lazy initialization
private List<Courses> courses;

// Getters and setters
}
```

Your Courses Entity class should be like

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Courses")
public class Courses {


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="COURSE_ID")
private long id;


@Column(name="COURSE_NAME")
private String name;


@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="Student_ID")    // Foreign Key 
private Student student;

}
```

Put this property to true if facing any issue for lazy initialization
"hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans"